# Xcode Amount of rows in table through Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

I am new in IOS and Xcode (v4) so I am trying some things up. I have created a view controller to which I have included some toolbar items, a navigation item and a tableview. I am using the storyboard to build the interface. My table view is consisted of static cells. My problem is that in the table view I am trying to increase the rows from 4 to 6 but they will not show up in the storyboard (it is shown to the scenes on the left though). Plus I can't find a way to make them appear. Can anyone explain me why is this happening?
Also in the UITableView is there a scrollbar object integrated in case rows overcome screen size?

Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Be aware that for submitting app to the AppStore you need Xcode 5.1 or higher.

Comment: I don't plan to submit an app to the AppStore anytime soon. I am just testing some stuff up. Thanks though @rckoenes

Comment: select the controller propertyInspector->size->freeform.then you can increase the size of ur VC

Comment: btw: why do you have so many Toolbars in Eco View? Have you forget that you can change Toolbar content from the code?

Answer (score 0):

You want to see your fifth and sixth cell in storyboard means select your tableview and scroll u able to see. In Simulator also u can scroll ur  table view to see the cells.The thing is if u designing in 3.5 inch screen means the available width and height is 320 * 480. In that top 64 for navigation bar and status bar.

Comment: I do select my table view but I can't see them.

Comment: U able to scroll your tableview in storyboard or not.